# Incorrect JSON result created for parent-child models in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display my parent child table in html using JSON serializing in AJAX call. However, the callback for getJson method does not fire. I assume this is due to invalid JSON created in my controller. But I dont find any issue there. My controller method is as :

```
public JsonResult GetJsonData(string search)
{
  var persons = db.Person.ToList().
                Where(p => p.FirstName == search || p.LastName == search).ToList();         
  JsonResult json = Json(persons, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  return json;
}
```

Also my models are as follows:

```
public class Person
{
   public Person()
   {
      this.Interests = new HashSet<Interest>();
   }

   [DisplayName("PersonID")]
   public int PersonID { get; set; }
   [DisplayName("FirstName")]
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   [DisplayName("LastName")]
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   [DisplayName("Address")]
   public string Address { get; set; }
   [DisplayName("Age")]
   public int? Age { get; set; }
   [DisplayName("Photo")]
   public string Photo { get; set; }
   [DisplayName("Interests")]
   public virtual ICollection<Interest> Interests { get; set; }
}
```

and the child class is:

```
public class Interest
{       
    [DisplayName("InterestId")]
    public int InterestId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("InterestValue")]
    public string InterestValue { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("PersonId")]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public virtual Person person { get; set; }
}
```

My view contains following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        $('#btnGetPersons').click(function () {
            var searchKey = $("#txtBoxPersonSearch").val();
            $.getJSON("/Person/GetJsonData", { search: searchKey }, function (data) {                
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    drawRow(data[i]);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function drawRow(rowData) {
        debugger;
        var row = $("<tr/>")
        var img = "<img src=" + "~/Images/" + rowData.Photo + " />";

        $("#personDataTable").append(row);
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.FirstName + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.LastName + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.Address + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.Age + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.Interests + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + img + "</td>"));
    }

</script>
```

Note that when I did not keep serialization on Interests entity in Person class, the table was populating with values except the Interests.

Now, when I debug the controller method, the JSON result seems correctly populated with Person data and Interest data within person data, but still my getJson method does not callback and I cannot populate the table with data. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Show the relevant script that issues the Ajax request

Comment: Invalid JSON is very unlikely given that you're using the `Json()` method to serialise your `List`. It would help if we could see your JS code. Have you checked the network console for errors at all? I would suspect either a routing issue, or a syntax error in your JS code.

Comment: Added the view code in  the question.

Comment: check the actual request in browser dev tools, always firt place to start debugging ajax

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a routing issue as in Rory's comment.

Change line 4 in the below:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#btnGetPersons').click(function() {
        var searchKey = $("#txtBoxPersonSearch").val();
        $.getJSON("/Person/GetJsonData", {
          search: searchKey
        }, function(data) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            drawRow(data[i]);
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

To this:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#btnGetPersons').click(function() {
        var searchKey = $("#txtBoxPersonSearch").val();
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetJsonData", "Person")', {
          search: searchKey
        }, function(data) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            drawRow(data[i]);
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

The difference is '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")' - this creates the correct relative path to your application resource.

Finally, try this in your controller:

```
return Json (new { result = persons } );
```

Then in your js change like this:

```
 $.getJSON("/Person/GetJsonData", { search: searchKey }, function (data) {                
            for (var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
                drawRow(data.result[i]);
            }
        });
```

One last thing to try is change your ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/controller/action',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET'
        }).success(function (data) {
           alert(data.result);
        }).error(function (xhr, status) {
           alert(status);
        })
```

Comment: I tried to run the code with your suggested update, but it does not work. The problem is I am not getting a callback from getJson method. It does go to the controller method GetJsonData but does not come back to the view.

Comment: I see. Also, are you getting any data back in the js function? A simple alert with the (data) would show the object. I have a feeling the data.length is = 0. Can you try Newtonsoft JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persons)?

Comment: I am not getting a callback to js function. I kept a debugger there, but it is never called. So I cannot check the data value

Comment: updated, please try calling your ajax with different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Along with with @Denys said about your `URL` you should also change your controller `GetJsonData` code.  Unless you have lazing loading turned on you won't get any interest information if you dont use `Include`.  And you should also filter on `search` before you do `ToList` or you'll get every Person record back from the database.

```
public JsonResult GetJsonData(string search)
{
    var persons = db.Person
                    .Include("Interests")
                    .Where(p => p.FirstName == search || p.LastName == search)
                    .ToList();

    return Json(persons, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Just realized you might be getting a `circular reference` error since `Interests` have a `Person` also. You should probably create a viewmodel instead of trying to serialize the entity.

Try returning an anonymous type and see if you get data back.

```
public JsonResult GetJsonData(string search)
{
    var persons = db.Person
                    .Include("Interests.Person")
                    .Where(p => p.FirstName == search || p.LastName == search)
                    .Select(p => new
                    {
                        FirstName = p.FirstName,
                        LastName = p.LastName,
                        Address = p.Address,
                        Age = p.Age,
                        Photo = p.Photo,
                        Interests = p.Interests.Select(i => new { 
                           FirstName = i.Person.FirstName,
                           LastName = i.Person.LastName
                        })
                    })
                    .ToList();

    return Json(persons, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); ;
}
```